# How to alter a table in DataBase in android application using ORMLite and retain the values

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ormlite

I want to alter a table in my android application which is using ORMLite. I will explain my scenario.

Let's say that someone download my app on the Google Play. Few months later I will certainly populate some tables with new entries.

When this person is doing an update of the app, how can I just alter a table in database with my new entries and keep the old ones inside it.

To be more clear, imagine that the user table is altered and i introduced a new field say 'city', how can i update the table with old values?

When i tried to back up the data from older table(which doesn't have 'city' field) with my new DAO Object with an attribute 'city', i was not able to fetch the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use the version number that is passed to the onUpgrade(...) method. With ORMLite, the OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.onUpgrade(...) method takes an oldVersion and newVersion number. You then can write conversion code into your application that is able to convert the data from the old format and update the schema.

For more details visits docs http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Upgrading-Schema

Most likely, you should make your schema changes conditional to the version you are upgrading from:

```
if (oldVersion < 2) {
  // we added the age column in version 2
  dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN age INTEGER;");
}
if (oldVersion < 3) {
  // we added the weight column in version 3
  dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN weight INTEGER;");
}
```

Comment: I tried this but i am getting an exception now - java.sql.SQLException: Unknown field 'city' from the Android sqlite cursor

Comment: please explain the scenario . From exception it is clear that city field does not exist.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted. Too bad OP doesn't know how to use StackOverflow.

Comment: Is this only way? This seems like really low support for altering tables. You have to manually find what version of database you are using and then apply changes... really bad